# Biblatex incorrectly using et. al. for three authors citation with apa style

Tags: biblatex

I have a problem where biblatex is incorrectly using the et. al. abbreviation for three-athor citations. If I understand correctly the APA style prescribes to show all authors for first and subsequent references with up to three authors.

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
@article{Gaynor2016,
author = {Gaynor, Martin and Propper, Carol and Seiler, Stephan},
doi = {10.1257/aer.20121532},
issn = {00028282},
journal = {American Economic Review},
number = {11},
pages = {3521--3557},
pmid = {29553210},
title = {{Free to choose? Reform, choice, and consideration sets in the English national health service}},
volume = {106},
year = {2016}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib} 

\begin{document}

\citet{Gaynor2016}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Screenshot]

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Note that the option `style=apa` no longer implements the 6th edition of the APA manual but, rather, the 7th edition. The outputs generated by the 6th and 7th editions differ in quite a few places. If you need the behavior of the 6th edition, you should specify `style=apa6` when loading `biblatex`.

Comment: This I did not know. The 7th edition says to also shorten the first three-author citation. If you add this as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Please see the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that biblatex's `style=apa` no longer implements the formatting guidelines of the 6th edition of the APA manual; the style now implements those of the 7th edition. The outputs generated by the 6th and 7th editions differ in quite a few places.

One of the changes pertains to treating citation call-outs for publications with three or more authors: The 7th edition says to truncate the call-out to "first surname et al" beginning with the very first citation. Another change affects what's shown if an entry has both a `doi` and a `url` field: In the 7th ed., the contents of the `url` field are shown, whereas in the 6th ed. the contents of the `doi` field were shown. (Either way, it's a good idea to load the `xurl` package to handle the typesetting of long URL strings.)

If you need the behavior of the 6th edition, you should specify `style=apa6` when loading `biblatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
% https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20121532
@article{gps:2016,
Author = {Gaynor, Martin and Propper, Carol and Seiler, Stephan},
Title  = {Free to Choose? {Reform}, Choice, and Consideration Sets in the {English National Health Service}},
Journal= {American Economic Review},
Volume = {106},
Number = {11},
Year   = {2016},
Month  = {November},
Pages  = {3521-57},
DOI    = {10.1257/aer.20121532},
URL    = {https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.20121532},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=apa]{biblatex} % set 'style=apa6' if 6th-ed. formatting is required
\addbibresource{mybib.bib}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{document}
\cite{gps:2016}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```